# How to make Controls in FlowPane Grow with Windows Maximising

Tags: java, javafx

[Window in default size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7gsH.png)

then

[Window maximised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnZVu.png)

I've create a key to show the containment of the controls:

[**Here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D043v.png)

I want the listviews inside the VBoxs to grow while maintaining their ratio.

Here is the code:

```
public class Modules extends BorderPane {

private Button Term1AddBtn, Term2AddBtn, Term2AddBtn, Term2RemoveBtn, ResetBtn, SubmitBtn;
private ListView Term1UnSelect, Term2UnSelect, Term1Select, Term2Select, YearSelect;
private TextField txtTerm1Cred, txtTerm1Cred;

public Modules() {
    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    flowPane.setHgap(20);
    flowPane.setVgap(20);
    this.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 20, 10)); 

    Label lblTerm1UnSel = new Label("Unselected Term 1 Modules");
    Label lblTerm2UnSel = new Label("Unselected Term 2 Modules");
    Label lblTerm1Sel   = new Label("Selected Term 1 Modules");
    Label lblTerm2Sel   = new Label("Selected Term 2 Modules");
    Label lblYearSel   = new Label("Selected Year Long Modules");
    Label lblTerm1Btns  = new Label("Term 1:");
    Label lblTerm2Btns  = new Label("Term 2:");
    Label lblTerm1Cred  = new Label("Current Term 1 Credits:");
    Label lblTerm2Cred  = new Label("Current Term 2 Credits:");

    Term1UnSelect = new ListView();
    Term2UnSelect = new ListView();
    Term1Select = new ListView();
    Term2Select = new ListView();
    YearSelect = new ListView();
    Term1AddBtn  = new Button("Add");
    Term1RemoveBtn   = new Button("Remove");
    Term2AddBtn  = new Button("Add");
    Term2RemoveBtn   = new Button("Remove");
    ResetBtn    = new Button("Reset");
    SubmitBtn    = new Button("Submit");
    txtTerm1Cred = new TextField("0");
    txtTerm1Cred = new TextField("0");


    Term1UnSelect.setPrefSize(350, 100);
    Term2UnSelect.setPrefSize(350, 100);
    Term1Select.setPrefSize(350, 100);
    Term2Select.setPrefSize(350, 100);
    YearSelect.setPrefSize(350, 50);
    txtTerm1Cred.setMaxWidth(50);
    txtTerm1Cred.setMaxWidth(50);
    Term1AddBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
    Term1RemoveBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
    Term2AddBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
    Term2RemoveBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
    ResetBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
    SubmitBtn.setPrefWidth(70);

    VBox vboxTerm1Unsel = new VBox();
    VBox vboxTerm2Unsel = new VBox();
    VBox vboxTerm1Sel   = new VBox();
    VBox vboxTerm2Sel   = new VBox();
    VBox vboxYear   = new VBox();
    HBox hboxTerm1Btns  = new HBox();
    HBox hboxTerm2Btns  = new HBox();
    HBox hboxTerm1Cred  = new HBox();
    HBox hboxTerm2Cred  = new HBox();
    HBox hboxResetSubmit= new HBox();

    hboxTerm1Btns.setSpacing(20);
    hboxTerm2Btns.setSpacing(20);
    hboxTerm1Cred.setSpacing(20);
    hboxTerm2Cred.setSpacing(20);
    hboxResetSubmit.setSpacing(20);

    vboxTerm1Unsel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1UnSel, Term1UnSelect);
    vboxTerm2Unsel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2UnSel, Term2UnSelect);
    vboxTerm1Sel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Sel, Term1Select);
    vboxTerm2Sel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Sel, Term2Select);
    vboxYear.getChildren().addAll(lblYearSel, YearSelect);
    hboxTerm1Btns.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Btns, Term1AddBtn, Term1RemoveBtn);
    hboxTerm2Btns.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Btns, Term2AddBtn, Term2RemoveBtn);
    hboxTerm1Cred.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Cred, txtTerm1Cred);
    hboxTerm2Cred.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Cred, txtTerm1Cred);
    hboxResetSubmit.getChildren().addAll(ResetBtn, SubmitBtn);

    hboxTerm1Btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hboxTerm2Btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hboxTerm1Cred.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hboxTerm2Cred.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hboxResetSubmit.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    flowPane.getChildren().addAll(vboxTerm1Unsel, hboxTerm1Btns, vboxTerm2Unsel, hboxTerm2Btns, hboxTerm1Cred, vboxYear, vboxTerm1Sel, vboxTerm2Sel, hboxTerm2Cred);

    BorderPane.setMargin(flowPane, new Insets(20));

    this.setCenter(flowPane);
    this.setBottom(hboxResetSubmit);

}
```

OR if possible, a way to keep the controls in the same format in a way like this:

[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4fOj.png)

**Have to bypass the more details part to post, sorry**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum laoreet tincidunt. Integer vitae magna venenatis nibh blandit dignissim. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc velit est, congue dignissim diam et, rhoncus mattis quam. Duis ultricies lectus vel mauris aliquet, nec ultrices augue vehicula. Ut cursus fringilla ipsum. Cras id feugiat metus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse vitae luctus risus. Proin ut tempor turpis, non vehicula nunc. Nam et sapien sit amet dui suscipit lacinia.

Comment: You need to post your `View` code.

Comment: You probably should not be using the `FlowPane`.

Comment: Is this done in pure code or `FXML`?

Comment: @Sedrick Pure code, using an MVC method, added the code as well, omitting the declarations/assignments that didn't matter

Comment: The code you left out does matter. I would have to retype all of that to run your code.

Comment: Sorry, I removed it because it required me to add more details in order to post it, I've put it in now

Comment: A `SplitPane` might look better than the `HBox` as the `rootHBox`, but I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed your `FlowPane` and replaced it with an `HBox`.

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Modules extends BorderPane {
    private final Button Term1AddBtn, Term1RemoveBtn, Term2AddBtn, Term2RemoveBtn, ResetBtn, SubmitBtn;
    private final ListView Term1UnSelect, Term2UnSelect, Term1Select, Term2Select, YearSelect;
    private final TextField txtTerm1Cred;

    public Modules() {
        HBox rootHBox = new HBox();

        this.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 20, 10)); 

        Label lblTerm1UnSel = new Label("Unselected Term 1 Modules");
        Label lblTerm2UnSel = new Label("Unselected Term 2 Modules");
        Label lblTerm1Sel   = new Label("Selected Term 1 Modules");
        Label lblTerm2Sel   = new Label("Selected Term 2 Modules");
        Label lblYearSel   = new Label("Selected Year Long Modules");
        Label lblTerm1Btns  = new Label("Term 1:");
        Label lblTerm2Btns  = new Label("Term 2:");
        Label lblTerm1Cred  = new Label("Current Term 1 Credits:");
        Label lblTerm2Cred  = new Label("Current Term 2 Credits:");

        Term1UnSelect = new ListView();
        Term2UnSelect = new ListView();
        Term1Select = new ListView();
        Term2Select = new ListView();
        YearSelect = new ListView();
        Term1AddBtn  = new Button("Add");
        Term1RemoveBtn   = new Button("Remove");
        Term2AddBtn  = new Button("Add");
        Term2RemoveBtn   = new Button("Remove");
        ResetBtn    = new Button("Reset");
        SubmitBtn    = new Button("Submit");
        txtTerm1Cred = new TextField("0");


        Term1UnSelect.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        Term2UnSelect.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        Term1Select.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        Term2Select.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        YearSelect.setPrefSize(350, 50);
        txtTerm1Cred.setMaxWidth(50);
        txtTerm1Cred.setMaxWidth(50);
        Term1AddBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        Term1RemoveBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        Term2AddBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        Term2RemoveBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        ResetBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        SubmitBtn.setPrefWidth(70);

        VBox vboxTerm1Unsel = new VBox();
        VBox vboxTerm2Unsel = new VBox();
        VBox vboxTerm1Sel   = new VBox();
        VBox vboxTerm2Sel   = new VBox();
        VBox vboxYear   = new VBox();
        HBox hboxTerm1Btns  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxTerm2Btns  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxTerm1Cred  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxTerm2Cred  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxResetSubmit= new HBox();

        hboxTerm1Btns.setSpacing(20);
        hboxTerm2Btns.setSpacing(20);
        hboxTerm1Cred.setSpacing(20);
        hboxTerm2Cred.setSpacing(20);
        hboxResetSubmit.setSpacing(20);

        vboxTerm1Unsel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1UnSel, Term1UnSelect);
        vboxTerm2Unsel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2UnSel, Term2UnSelect);
        vboxTerm1Sel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Sel, Term1Select);
        vboxTerm2Sel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Sel, Term2Select);
        vboxYear.getChildren().addAll(lblYearSel, YearSelect);
        hboxTerm1Btns.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Btns, Term1AddBtn, Term1RemoveBtn);
        hboxTerm2Btns.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Btns, Term2AddBtn, Term2RemoveBtn);
        hboxTerm1Cred.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Cred, txtTerm1Cred);
        hboxTerm2Cred.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Cred, txtTerm1Cred);
        hboxResetSubmit.getChildren().addAll(ResetBtn, SubmitBtn);

        hboxTerm1Btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxTerm2Btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxTerm1Cred.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxTerm2Cred.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxResetSubmit.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        VBox leftVBox = new VBox(vboxTerm1Unsel, hboxTerm1Btns, vboxTerm2Unsel, hboxTerm2Btns, hboxTerm1Cred);
        leftVBox.setSpacing(5);
        VBox rightVBox = new VBox(vboxYear, vboxTerm1Sel, vboxTerm2Sel, hboxTerm2Cred);
        rightVBox.setSpacing(5);
        rootHBox.getChildren().addAll(leftVBox, rightVBox);
        rootHBox.setSpacing(5);
        rootHBox.setMaxSize(USE_PREF_SIZE, USE_PREF_SIZE);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(rootHBox, Pos.CENTER);
        this.setCenter(new StackPane(rootHBox));
        this.setBottom(hboxResetSubmit);

    }
}
```

Here is a stretched version.

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Modules extends BorderPane {
    private final Button Term1AddBtn, Term1RemoveBtn, Term2AddBtn, Term2RemoveBtn, ResetBtn, SubmitBtn;
    private final ListView Term1UnSelect, Term2UnSelect, Term1Select, Term2Select, YearSelect;
    private final TextField txtTerm1Cred;

    public Modules() {
        HBox rootHBox = new HBox();

        this.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 20, 10)); 

        Label lblTerm1UnSel = new Label("Unselected Term 1 Modules");
        Label lblTerm2UnSel = new Label("Unselected Term 2 Modules");
        Label lblTerm1Sel   = new Label("Selected Term 1 Modules");
        Label lblTerm2Sel   = new Label("Selected Term 2 Modules");
        Label lblYearSel   = new Label("Selected Year Long Modules");
        Label lblTerm1Btns  = new Label("Term 1:");
        Label lblTerm2Btns  = new Label("Term 2:");
        Label lblTerm1Cred  = new Label("Current Term 1 Credits:");
        Label lblTerm2Cred  = new Label("Current Term 2 Credits:");

        Term1UnSelect = new ListView();
        Term2UnSelect = new ListView();
        Term1Select = new ListView();
        Term2Select = new ListView();
        YearSelect = new ListView();
        Term1AddBtn  = new Button("Add");
        Term1RemoveBtn   = new Button("Remove");
        Term2AddBtn  = new Button("Add");
        Term2RemoveBtn   = new Button("Remove");
        ResetBtn    = new Button("Reset");
        SubmitBtn    = new Button("Submit");
        txtTerm1Cred = new TextField("0");


        Term1UnSelect.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        Term2UnSelect.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        Term1Select.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        Term2Select.setPrefSize(350, 100);
        YearSelect.setPrefSize(350, 50);
        txtTerm1Cred.setMaxWidth(50);
        txtTerm1Cred.setMaxWidth(50);
        Term1AddBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        Term1RemoveBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        Term2AddBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        Term2RemoveBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        ResetBtn.setPrefWidth(70);
        SubmitBtn.setPrefWidth(70);

        VBox vboxTerm1Unsel = new VBox();
        VBox vboxTerm2Unsel = new VBox();
        VBox vboxTerm1Sel   = new VBox();
        VBox vboxTerm2Sel   = new VBox();
        VBox vboxYear   = new VBox();
        HBox hboxTerm1Btns  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxTerm2Btns  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxTerm1Cred  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxTerm2Cred  = new HBox();
        HBox hboxResetSubmit= new HBox();

        hboxTerm1Btns.setSpacing(20);
        hboxTerm2Btns.setSpacing(20);
        hboxTerm1Cred.setSpacing(20);
        hboxTerm2Cred.setSpacing(20);
        hboxResetSubmit.setSpacing(20);

        vboxTerm1Unsel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1UnSel, Term1UnSelect);
        vboxTerm2Unsel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2UnSel, Term2UnSelect);
        vboxTerm1Sel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Sel, Term1Select);
        vboxTerm2Sel.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Sel, Term2Select);
        vboxYear.getChildren().addAll(lblYearSel, YearSelect);
        hboxTerm1Btns.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Btns, Term1AddBtn, Term1RemoveBtn);
        hboxTerm2Btns.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Btns, Term2AddBtn, Term2RemoveBtn);
        hboxTerm1Cred.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm1Cred, txtTerm1Cred);
        hboxTerm2Cred.getChildren().addAll(lblTerm2Cred, txtTerm1Cred);
        hboxResetSubmit.getChildren().addAll(ResetBtn, SubmitBtn);

        hboxTerm1Btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxTerm2Btns.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxTerm1Cred.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxTerm2Cred.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hboxResetSubmit.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        VBox.setVgrow(Term1UnSelect, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(Term2UnSelect, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(Term1Select, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(Term2Select, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(YearSelect, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox.setVgrow(vboxTerm1Unsel, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(vboxTerm2Unsel, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(vboxYear, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(vboxTerm1Sel, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(vboxTerm2Sel, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox leftVBox = new VBox(vboxTerm1Unsel, hboxTerm1Btns, vboxTerm2Unsel, hboxTerm2Btns, hboxTerm1Cred);
        leftVBox.setSpacing(5);
        HBox.setHgrow(leftVBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

        VBox rightVBox = new VBox(vboxYear, vboxTerm1Sel, vboxTerm2Sel, hboxTerm2Cred);
        rightVBox.setSpacing(5);
        HBox.setHgrow(rightVBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

        rootHBox.getChildren().addAll(leftVBox, rightVBox);
        rootHBox.setSpacing(5);
        rootHBox.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(rootHBox, Pos.CENTER);
        this.setCenter(new StackPane(rootHBox));
        this.setBottom(hboxResetSubmit);

    }
}
```

You can play with the spacing on both.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you, I tunnel visioned pretty hard on the idea of using a FlowPane, I felt it was wrong but I couldn't think of what else I could do, thanks for the help! :)